# No response received within reply timeout?

Tags: smack

I have used the smack api to make a xmpp client. and for creating a roster entry i used the following code.

```
public void likeOnXmpp(UserFriendsBaseModel userFriendsBaseModel) {
        AbstractXMPPConnection con = null;
        try {

            con = new SecuredXmppConnectionImpl(SecuredXmppConnectionImpl.getConfig(xmppResource.getXmppHost(), Integer.parseInt(xmppResource.getXmppSSLPort()))).connect();

            if (con != null) {
                xmppLogin(con, String.valueOf(userFriendsBaseModel.getUserId()), generatePassword(userFriendsBaseModel.getUserId()));

                addFriendInXMPP(String.valueOf(userFriendsBaseModel.getUserId()),
                        generatePassword(userFriendsBaseModel.getUserId()),
                        String.valueOf(userFriendsBaseModel.getFriendId()),
                        String.valueOf(generatePassword(userFriendsBaseModel
                                .getFriendId())),
                        getProfileName(userFriendsBaseModel.getFriendId()), con);

                removeRosterFailureRequest(userFriendsBaseModel);
            } else {
                addRosterFailureRequest(userFriendsBaseModel);
                logger.info("LIKE saved in Roster Failure : "+userFriendsBaseModel.getUserId()+" -> "+userFriendsBaseModel.getFriendId());
            }

        } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException
                | InternalServerError e1) {
            logger.error("unable to login at xmpp ", e1);
            addRosterFailureRequest(userFriendsBaseModel);
            logger.info("LIKE saved in Roster Failure : "+userFriendsBaseModel.getUserId()+" -> "+userFriendsBaseModel.getFriendId());
        }
```

add Roster method code as :

```
private void addFriendInXMPP(String username, String password, String contactUserName, String contactPassword, String name,
            AbstractXMPPConnection userConnection) throws InternalServerError {
        try {
            userConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(20000);
            xmppRosterManager.createEntry(userConnection, getBareJID(contactUserName), name, new String[] { "Friends" });
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            logger.error("unable to create roster entry : ", e);
            throw new InternalServerError();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            logger.error("unable to create roster entry : ", e);
            throw new InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

and createEntry :

```
@Override
    public void createEntry(AbstractXMPPConnection connection, String jId, String name, String[] groups) 
            throws XMPPException, NotLoggedInException, NoResponseException, NotConnectedException {
        //getting instance of a roster
        Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(SubscriptionMode.manual);
        Roster.getInstanceFor(connection).createEntry(jId, name, groups); // adding a entry in roster
    }
```

this is the code of SecuredXmppConnectionImpl class

```
public class SecuredXmppConnectionImpl extends XmppConnectionImpl {

    public SecuredXmppConnectionImpl(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config) {
        super(config);
    }

    /**
     * Returns default configuration for Old SSL port method
     * 
     * @param serviceName
     * @param port
     * @return
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException
     */
    public static XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration getConfig(String serviceName,
            int port) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslcontext.init(
                    null, // KeyManager not required
                    new TrustManager[] { new DummyTrustManager() },
                    new java.security.SecureRandom());
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
            return XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setServiceName(serviceName).setHost(serviceName).setPort(port)
                    .setSocketFactory(ssf).build(); 
    }

    static class DummyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert) {
            try {
                cert[0].checkValidity();
                return true;
            } catch (CertificateExpiredException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (CertificateNotYetValidException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                String s) throws CertificateException {
            // Do nothing for now.
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                String s) throws CertificateException {
            // Do nothing for now.
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }

}
```

but sometimes i getting the Error as :

```
 key =javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@15f8b
2016-03-09 05:15:50,834 [http-bio-8080-exec-698] INFO  (TokenHelper.java:81) - token valid
2016-03-09 05:15:50,872 [_bgExecutor-2] ERROR (UserManagerImpl.java:899) - unable to create roster entry : 
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 20000ms (~20s). Used filter: IQReplyFilter: iqAndIdFilter (AndFilter: (OrFilter: (IQTypeFilter: type=error, IQTypeFilter: type=result), StanzaIdFilter: id=bb8Lb-1268146)), : fromFilter (OrFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): null, FromMatchesFilter (bare): 9223370581384268972@prdmastchat01.matchstixapp.com, FromMatchesFilter (full): prdmastchat01.matchstixapp.com)).
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:90)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:229)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:213)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster.createEntry(Roster.java:484)
    at com.craterzone.xmpprestconnector.user.impl.XMPPRosterManagerImpl.createEntry(XMPPRosterManagerImpl.java:31)
    at com.craterzone.matchstix.manager.impl.UserManagerImpl.addFriendInXMPP(UserManagerImpl.java:894)
    at com.craterzone.matchstix.manager.impl.UserManagerImpl.likeOnXmpp(UserManagerImpl.java:462)
    at com.craterzone.matchstix.manager.impl.UserManagerImpl$3.run(UserManagerImpl.java:411)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-03-09 05:15:50,872 [_bgExecutor-2] ERROR (UserManagerImpl.java:477) - unable to login at xmpp 
com.craterzone.matchstix.exception.InternalServerError: Server Error
    at com.craterzone.matchstix.manager.impl.UserManagerImpl.addFriendInXMPP(UserManagerImpl.java:900)
    at com.craterzone.matchstix.manager.impl.UserManagerImpl.likeOnXmpp(UserManagerImpl.java:462)
    at com.craterzone.matchstix.manager.impl.UserManagerImpl$3.run(UserManagerImpl.java:411)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Mar 09, 2016 5:15:50 AM org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: conflict You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
<stream:error><conflict xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:994)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:935)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:950)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i unable to recognize the problem , how can i fix it ? or what i need to do for listening the reply stanza with the given time ?

Thanks in advance